# IE does not properly use it's local cache for intranet sites and returns HTTP 200 instead of HTTP 304

Tags: iis, group-policy, cache, website, internet-explorer

I am a developer facing a problem at work. When I create any kind of .Net web application (ASP.Net, ASP.Net MVC), deploy it on my local machine's IIS or as an intranet application on our intranet IIS server and run it in a browser I get an unexpected result in IE.

Normally when you first access a site the files are downloaded and stored in the browser's local cache. On subsequent visits the browser sends a request to the server with the files Etags or last modified date. The server can respond with HTTP 304 if the files haven't changed thus preventing a full transfer of the file.

On my work network this works as expected for all browsers **except** IE who always returns HTTP 200 and thus downloads the file again.

I can start a new project in Visual Studio and caching works fine for other browsers but not IE. If I create the same project at home (on my own computer), caching works fine for all browsers **including** IE.

This makes me believe that there is something interfering with the process. Possibly some IE configuration (which is controlled by a Group Policy which I do not have access or maybe an IIS configuration, which again I do not have access or something else entirely.

I have access to IE's temporary files and I can see that the files are present in this folder.

What could be causing this? I need some information before approaching the sysadmins.

*Headers under Fiddler*

[image: Headers under Fiddler]

*Developer Tools Network tab*

[image: Developer Tools Network tab]

**EDIT:**

Here is a new project that I created and hosted in Visual Studio's IIS Express:

IE First Load:
[image]

Firefox First Load:
[image]

IE Second Load:
[image]
As we can see all the requests are 200 and the total time is sensibly the same.

Firefox Second Load:
[image]
As we can see, all requests after the main one are 304 and the total time is less than half of the first load.

Comment: IE does no such thing. It is the server that would return those status codes but could you have mis-written that? Having problems with IE is normal and expected.

Comment: @Rob: The thing that is puzzling is that's it's working fine in Firefox. It's also working fine with the same code at home under IE and Firefox. If there is a problem with the header it should not work under any browser. Also I don't like the idea that "having problems with IE is normal" particularly when other instances of IE (at home) or at previous jobs did not have this exact same problem.

Comment: Then you need to post the network requests from your browser developer tools or whatever you are seeing this with.

Comment: Are the sites HTTPS?  Is IE configured to cache HTTPS sites?

Comment: @msemack The sites are not on HTTPS.

Comment: @Rob I added images with the Headers and the results of the Network tab as you suggested. I also added images comparing IE and Firefox on their first and second load of a page.

Comment: The only thing I know for sure is IE sucks and it always has.

Comment: @Rob let's just say it's not my browser of choice either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After working on the problem I have found out this was due to the Internet Explorer Developer Tools in IE 11.

I found it out by opening Fiddler and the Internet Explorer Developer Tools at the same time.

If I hit refresh while the Developer Tools were open on the Network tab, the Dev Tools and Fiddler would register all HTTP 200.

On the other hand if I hit refresh while the Dev Tool were closed and Fiddler was open, Fiddler would register HTTP 304.

So it's the Dev Tool that are forcing the browser not to use the cache. As suggested by **Saravanan** in the comments, this is a configuration in the Dev-Tools in IE 11:

[image: Internet Explorer - Dev Tools - always refresh from server]

This did not happen when I tried the same tests at home because I was using IE Edge at home and IE 11 at work. This option has been changed in Edge which caused the difference in results.

Comment: This is because the Always refresh from server is selected by default in the developer tools in IE